# Using web3.js to do base58 (ipfs) encoding and decoding?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, ipfs, encoding

Is it possible to use the web3.js libary to do base58 encoding and decoding?

It seems that [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#tobn) includes the [bignumber library](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/), but I'm unsure as to whether this can handle the base58 encoding used, for example, by ipfs.

I'm hoping for a function that looks a bit like this (which fails):
E.g. (based on [this](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/misc/bs58/))

```
web3.utils.toBN('QmXGTaGWTT1uUtfSb2sBAvArMEVLK4rQEcQg5bv7wwdzwU', 58) //web3 v1.x
```

or

```
web3.toBigNumber("QmXGTaGWTT1uUtfSb2sBAvArMEVLK4rQEcQg5bv7wwdzwU",58) //web3 v0.x
```

which returns a bignumber integer from the base58 number.
**Is it possible to do base58 encoding and decoding using the web3.js library?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web3.js doesn't provide a base58 encoder/decoder because it's only concerned with interfacing to ethereum, so there's no direct use of this feature. You'll have to use a module such as [bs58](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58).

Here's an example:

```
const bs58 = require('bs58')
const BN = require('bn.js')

const hash = 'QmXGTaGWTT1uUtfSb2sBAvArMEVLK4rQEcQg5bv7wwdzwU'
const hex = bs58.decode(hash).toString('hex')

console.log(hex) // 122084a644bfcb8639e1b1a1fc72fd0ad1826b91f7a9baa06ad409ac3c02b31f981b

const n = new BN(hex, 16)
console.log(n.toString(10)) // 537335293128262426148241029128274019001757729355677528305490323656269309818148891
```